Make a circular hole from a vertex in geometry nodes
I'd like to create perfectly circular holes from a bunch of vertices in a quad-based mesh through geonodes. The output would basically be what comes out after beveling a vertex, making it circular and adding the "diagonals" in order to have an only-quad result.

The previous image depicts the vertex I want to bevel and the result I expect.
I was able to reach a circle but only under specific circumstances and I'd like to make it a bit more robust.
The approach I pursued is the following:

For obvious limitations of this method, if the overall shape is not a square, I end up with the following result:

This is due to the fact that the inset do provides the diagonals but forcing their distance from a center without forcing every point of the circle to be also equidistant from each other results in a weird circumference.
Thanks a lot in advance!
M.
EDIT:

Normal Issue (solved)

This is the output without "recalculating" the normals

And this the fix to recalculate normals


Circle Rotation Issue (To be addressed)





Is it always a single face? If not, always 2d?

@DanielMöller I'd need it to work on a cylinder for instance, so in 3d

Got this working for quad-meshes and 4-poles.
As you can see, it will sort of fail if the vertice is a 3-pole, for instance (the extreme corner of the cube). I think it's not very hard to fix this if necessary. We probably just need to merge the neighbors by distance, count the number of neighbors and make a circle with that number of points.

Main nodes
Provided you have a float attribute (or vertex group) indicating the vertices that are hole centers (value = 1), we can loop through the hole centers making holes like this:

Repeat zone, iterations = number of holes
Since we're changing the geometry in the loop, we store the New Index attribute so we can use it for selection
Get the hole point, and in one side we delete it
In the other side, we get the neighbor/outer points, rotate them onto XY, centered at 0,0 and sort them by angle around the center
Get a circle and align this circle to the hole (center position and rotations)
Extrude the circle
Set the extruded positions to the positions of the neighbor/outer points
Join the extrusion with the main geometry


Get Hole Point

Separate the hole points
Get the "New Index" of the first hole point (this point will not be here in the next iteration, so it's ok to always get the first)
Return the new index, the selection, the position and the normal of this point in the main geometry


Get sorted contour

Given the center point (hole point)
Selects the 8 neighbor points
Stores their original indices to use later (because we're going to sort them)
Rotates them to put them onto the XY plane (according to the location and rotation/normal of the hole point)
Stores their rotation angle around the XY 0,0 (polar coordinates)
Sorts the neighor points by angle, we want the sequence of neighbors to follow the sequence of a circle's points.
Returns the original neighbor points (to sample their positions later) and the neighbors projected onto XY (to sample by proximity to the circle for rotating the circle later)


Aligned circle

Makes a circle with 8 vertices
Sorts the circle points by distance to the neares point in the projected neighbor points (we will align the circle to the neighbors by the shortest distance)
Samples for the first circle point (the neares) these two values from the projected neighbors:

Index of the nearest neighbor
Angle (around XY 0,0) of the nearest neighbor


Rotates the circle around itself following two rules:

Match indices with the sorted neighbors
The nearest pair (circle-neighbor) share the same rotation around XY 0,0.


Rotate it to align with the hole axis (normal of the hole point)
Position it at the center of the hole


Extrude circle

Extrudes the circle
Samples for each new point the position of the original neighbor points

This sampling passes through the sorted projected neighbors (which match index with the circle offset by 8 due to the extrusion)
And gets the original index of the non sorted neighbors to sample their position


Sets the circle position to the neighbors


Details on neighbor selection
Surrounding indices
This group takes the indices of 4 connected points (connected by edge) and 4 opposite points (on the opposite side of each face).
The logic of the connected points and opposite points groups follow the same logic as "edges of vertex" and "corners of vertex", as they use a sort index to get each edge/face corner.

Connected vertex

Gets one of the edges (based on sort index)
Gets both vertices of the edge
Returns the index of the vertice that does not have the same position as the current vertex


Opposite vertex

Gets one of the face corners (based on sort index)
Trusts the face has 4 sides and offsets two corners to get the opposite corner
Returns the index of the vertex of that corner


Select surrounding

Just takes the 8 indices of the neighor vertices and make a sequence of "or" operations to make a selection that returns these 8 vertices


File


Thanks Daniel! There are a couple of issues I found. The first concerning the inconsistent normal direction that I managed to fix by myself performing a dot product between the "point normal" returned in the "Get Hole Point" group and the face normal of the generated geo. The latter is a small issue about circle rotation if the setup is applied to a stretched grid like the one described in my question. I'm going to upload an edit with a reference of the problem.

Yeah... I noticed that... didn't have time to think about it, though. My first idea (probably not the best) is to create a subloop rotating the circle incrementally to reduce the sum of lengths of the "side"edges of the extrusion.

I was thinking about a method that could involve vertex sliding like while double-tapping "G" in edit mode but I have to think harder about it. In this way one could utilize edge "tangent" in order to fix the circle rotation.

@MarcoDiVita, fixed. Used the idea of aligning the rotation of the circle by the shortest distance. Was able to avoid a second loop
